# How can I embed one file into another with Ant?

Tags: ant, groovy, build

I am developing a small web app project (ColdFusion) and I am trying to keep my project split into multiple files during development, but deploy just one file on completion.

I have references to external files, for instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="project.css" />
```

And when I build my project, I want to have the files included and embedded within the single finished product file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r) [...]</script>
<style type="text/css">div{font:normal;} [...]</style>
```

Anyway, it doesn't look like there is a basic way for Ant to do this. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after a few hours of hacking...

```
<script language="groovy" src="build.groovy" />
```

and this groovy script replaces any referenced javascript or css file with the file contents itself.

```
f = new File("${targetDir}/index.cfm")
fContent = f.text
fContent = jsReplace(fContent)
fContent = cssReplace(fContent)
f.write(fContent)

// JS Replacement
def jsReplace(htmlFileText) {
    println "Groovy: Replacing Javascript includes"
    // extract all matched javascript src links
    def jsRegex = /<script [^>]*src=\"([^\"]+)\"><\/script>/
    def matcher = (htmlFileText =~ jsRegex)
    for (i in matcher) {
        // read external files in
        def includeText = new File(matcher.group(1)).text
        // sanitize the string for being regex replace string (dollar signs like jQuery/Prototype will screw it up)
        includeText = java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement(includeText)
        // weak compression (might as well)
        includeText = includeText.replaceAll(/\/\/.*/, "") // remove single-line comments (like this!)
        includeText = includeText.replaceAll(/[\n\r\f\s]+/, " ") // replace all whitespace with single space
        // return content with embedded file
        htmlFileText = htmlFileText.replaceFirst('<script [^>]*src="'+ matcher.group(1) +'"[^>]*></script>', '<script type="text/javascript">'+ includeText+'</script>');
    }
    return htmlFileText;
}

// CSS Replacement
def cssReplace(htmlFileText) {
    println "Groovy: Replacing CSS includes"
    // extract all matched CSS style href links
    def cssRegex = /<link [^>]*href=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>(<\/link>)?/
    def matcher = (htmlFileText =~ cssRegex)
    for (i in matcher) {
        // read external files in
        def includeText = new File(matcher.group(1)).text
        // compress CSS
        includeText = includeText.replaceAll(/[\n\r\t\f\s]+/, " ")
        // sanitize the string for being regex replace string (dollar signs like jQuery/Prototype will screw it up)
        includeText = java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement(includeText)
        // return content with embedded file
        htmlFileText = htmlFileText.replaceFirst('<link [^>]*href="'+ matcher.group(1) +'"[^>]*>(<\\/link>)?', '<style type=\"text/css\">'+ includeText+'</style>');
    }
    return htmlFileText;
}
```

So I guess that does it for me. It's been working pretty well, and it's extensible. Definitely not the best Groovy ever, but it's one of my first. Also, it required a few classpathed jars for it to compile. I lost track of which, but I believe it is the javax.scripting engine, groovy-engine.jar and groovy-all-1.5.6.jar

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, sorry but I'm going to pick my own answer, as it's more extensible for the future. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
<property
    name="filename"
    value="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"
/>

<loadfile
    property="contents"
    srcfile="${filename}"
/>

<replace dir=".">
    <include name="index.cfm"/>
    <replacetoken><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="${filename}"></script>]]></replacetoken>
    <replacevalue><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">${contents}</script>]]></replacevalue>
</replace>
```

Comment: Peter, thanks for your suggestion. This solution is not working for me. I just get:

    <script type="text/javascript">${jQueryContents}</script>

I tried it with and without the CDATA blocks with no change. it IS loading the ${jQueryContent} value, but not replacing it in the file.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution in pure ant, try the following:

```
<target name="replace">
    <property name="js-filename" value="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"/>
    <property name="css-filename" value="project.css"/>
    <loadfile property="js-file" srcfile="${js-filename}"/>
    <loadfile property="css-file" srcfile="${css-filename}"/>
    <replace file="input.txt">
        <replacefilter token="&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;${js-filename}&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;" value="&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;${js-file}&lt;/script&gt;"/>
        <replacefilter token="&lt;link type=&quot;text/css&quot; rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;${css-filename}&quot; /&gt;" value="&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;${css-file}&lt;/style&gt;"/>
    </replace>
</target>
```

I tested it, and it worked as expected. In the text to replace and the value you insert instead all characters '<', '>' and '"' should be quoted as &lt;, &gt; and &quot.